# React fixed navbar with flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

so I'm trying to create my blog using the react framework, but I'm facing an issue here.
I really have been trying to tweaks settings on the css, html or even try to switch to grid instead of flexbox but I can't figure out how to make the "fixed" navbar detected by the flexbox.

Currently, the navbar works fine I guess, but the content that is supposed to be on the right, is not taking the place it should, it's taking the entire screen instead of the rigth section next to the navbar.

Some help would be highly appreciated !

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*left box -Navbar*/

.nav-tab-text{
  font-size: 1.6em;
  display: block;
  padding: 00px 0px 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-tab a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.nav-tab {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 18%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  position: fixed;
}


/*Right box - Home content*/

.home-content-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid green;

}

.home-content-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
}

.home-content-featured{
  border: 3px solid purple;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.test{
  display: flex;

}
```

```
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="flex-container">
      {/*left box - Navbar*/}
      <nav className="nav-tab">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Articles</a>
            <a href="#">Archives</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
      </nav>
      
      {/*Right box - Home content*/}
      <div className="home-content-container">
        <div className="home-content-title">
            <h3>Name</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="home-content-featured">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="test">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

```
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*left box -Navbar*/

.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.nav-tab a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: aliceblue;

}

.nav-tab {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 18%;
  border: 3px solid red;
}


/*Right box - Home content*/

.home-content-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;

}

.home-content-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
}

.home-content-featured{
  border: 3px solid purple;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).